# Reading and writing to/from files from another PC using C

Tags: c, linux, windows-7, fopen

I have a a small RISC machine running Linux connected to my PC(win7) with a cross-over cable. I can connect fine. I write c code on the PC using "make" and then "scp" to transfer the program to the Linux machine. All that works well.
I now want to create a file on the win7 machine using the Linux machine. My `fopen` is the following:

```
fp = fopen("\\\\169.254.5.151\\temp\\test.txt", "w+");
```

On the win7 PC, I have a folder in "c:\" named temp where on the bottom of the explorer window, the state is shared. The IP address you see is that of the win7 PC. When I run the c code on the Linux machine, the temp folder remains empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I run the c code on the Linux machine, the temp folder remains empty." --> Linux may not understand `'\\'`. Try using `'/'` on both platforms.

Comment: The path you've expressed might not be recognisable to your Linux machine; it appears to be a netbios path, which isn't necessarily supported in Linux by default. You'll probably need to install SAMBA, which makes the answer to this question (and this question itself) irrelevant to this website.

Comment: I tried '/' and I got a Segmentation fault.